# How can I find a shapefile for GP surgery locations in the UK

Tags: data, united-kingdom

I am doing some research on accessibility to GP surgeries in South Norfolk and want to find a GIS data file with all the GP surgeries' locations on it that could be used in ArcMap.

Is there anywhere online I can find this? I have been looking for quite a while but cannot find anything.

Comment: I don't know if such a georeferenced file would exist in a publicly available format (as you seem to be finding).  You could try the regional Helath Boards.  Failing that, if you could get a list of all the addresses for the surgeries, you could geocode (perhaps using the postcode) them and make your own.

Comment: last time I did this we scraped the DoH web site and geocoded using the PAF file.

Comment: I think geocoding will be the way to go, wanted to avoid that though as it can be so time consuming!

Answer (score 2):

Try this link 
The information presented here provides details of the location of all 10,776 GP practices and branch surgeries in England, which were operating on April 2004. 97.9% of the data have been successfully geo-referenced. 230 (2.1%) surgeries were not geo-referenced, therefore will not appear as points in this dataset.

http://data.gov.uk/dataset/location_of_general_practices_gps_-_surgeries

Answer (score 1):

This NHS site has GeoJSON files for GP practices

https://digital.nhs.uk/data-and-information/data-collections-and-data-sets/data-collections/general-practice-data-collections

Direct link to data current at October 2022

https://nhs-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/content/assets/website-assets/data-and-information/data-collections/general-practice-data-collections/edec_catchment_area_geojson_data_04_10_22.zip